# Assigning parameters of one DTO to another

Tags: asp.net, object, append, dto, class-library

This is code for assigning parameters of one DTO to another

```
List<Projectdto> matchedProjects = new List<Projectdto>();
List<Projectdto> obj1 = new List<Projectdto>();
List<ProjectDTO> obj = matchedProjectsDetails;
Projectdto projectdto = new Projectdto();
for (int i = 0; i < matchedProjectsDetails.Count; i++)
{
    projectdto.Name = obj[i].Name;
    projectdto.PID = obj[i].PID;
    projectdto.PNKC = obj[i].MatchedPNKC;
    projectdto.PNKCCount = obj[i].MatchedPnkcCount;
    obj1.Add(projectdto);                                    
}
```

Here, after execute for loop obj1 had same array of parameters, Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Move `Projectdto projectdto = new Projectdto();` inside `for` loop. Also I would say using `foreach` can be more readable here. Or maybe even better is to switch to the LINQ.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Cant use foreach because both DTOs having different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Move `Projectdto projectdto = new Projectdto();` inside your loop, you are just altering one item at the moment rather than creating a new copy for each iteration of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matchedProjectsDetails.Count; i++)
{
     Projectdto projectdto = new Projectdto(); 
     projectdto.Name = obj[i].Name;
     projectdto.PID = obj[i].PID;
     projectdto.PNKC = obj[i].MatchedPNKC;
     projectdto.PNKCCount = obj[i].MatchedPnkcCount;
     obj1.Add(projectdto);                                    
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this will not repeat the instances. Thanks